# Which one is best js minifier used in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, javascript

I have the big project developed in the javascript framework. Hence its necessary to minify all the js so as the speed may enhance.

Please tell which js minifier software will best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Closure Tools project. It is an effort by Google engineers to open source the tools used in many of Google's sites and web applications for use by the wider Web development community.

you can use it from:

[Closure Tools — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/closure/?csw=1)

documentation could be found:

[Closure Compiler Documentation - Closure Tools — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/overview?csw=1)

---

If you want an Ubuntu application you can use yui-compressor.This is not the best option but it's probably the easiest. It's JavaScript/CSS minifier.

you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install yui-compressor
```

You can run yui-compressor myfile.js and it'll do all for you :)

Comment: I have installed the "yui-compressor". But I want to know the command which compress the all files in folder and it's subfolders too.
I able to do it for files exist in folder but it is not in subfolder.
Do you have any solution?